# Dependency Structure Matrix issue of SonarQube 4.5.4

Tags: matrix, dependencies, sonarqube

I use SonarQube 4.5.4 to scan Java project and find out the dependency file number in dependency structure matrix is not correct. For example the number shows 3, but click it, there are only 2 files. All of numbers are equals to actual number +1. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the sonarqube java plugin that won't be fixed as the feature is planned to be dropped : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1184